# C++ - Cast char reference to bool referenece (std::vector<bool>)

Tags: c++, vector, casting, reference

I have a problem casting a char reference to a bool reference. I have a simple GUI library that has the following method `gui->addButton(string name, bool& value);`. If the button is clicked the bool is flipped. Now I want to have a dynamic/unknown amout of buttons. Hence I though I could create a vector of bools, simply push_back a new bool for every button created and give the addButton method a reference to the last vector element. Something like this:

```
bool isOnFlag = true;
buttonFlagVector.push_back(isOnFlag);
gui->addButton(name, buttonFlagVector.back());
```

Sadly because of the [specialization of vector for bools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_%28C%2B%2B%29#Specialization_for_bool), that doesn't work.

From what I read the common way to avoid the specialization for bool is to use a `std::vector<char>`. I tried that and the problem I am having is that I don't know how to cast from a char reference to a bool reference. `dynamic_cast` `reinterpret_cast`? None of them seem to work.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code that doesn't work?

Comment: And what does "doesn't work" mean? Compiler error, runtime error, unexpected program behavior?

Comment: I think you should do `reinterpret_cast<bool&>(buttonFlagVector.back())`

Comment: @Giulio: That clear, but Foaly also stated, that a cast from std::vector<char> doesn't work which is not covered by the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the size of a `bool` is implementation defined and may differ on different compilers. So even though a `reinterpret_cast` could work, I would recommend against it. Instead you could use a small wrapper `struct` like this:

```
struct SpecialBool { bool b; };
std::vector<SpecialBool> bools;
```

Unfortunately you also have another problem with your approach in that you cant store references to elements in a `std::vector` while you are still adding elements to it. On each `push_back` the internal memory may be reallocated which will invalidate all your previous references.

Comment: As a workaround, if you know the number of buttons in advance (which is usually the case), you can pre-allocate the space you need with the `reserve` method. Or, even better, use `std::array`. If you use `array`, you don't even have the problem of `bool` specialization.

Comment: OK cool! Thanks for the help! I think I will settel with a `std::array` to avoid the problem of invalidating all references on reallocation. It sucks because I have to define a max amount of buttons, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `bool` in your `struct` to avoid `std::vector<bool>` specialization:

```
struct buttonState
{
    bool checked;
};

std::vector<buttonState> buttonStates;
```

And latter:

```
bool isOnFlag = true;
buttonFlagVector.push_back({isOnFlag});
gui->addButton(name, buttonFlagVector.back().checked);
```

Comment: This is right, but the issue pointed out by Tafuri is really relevant, since reallocation would break this code with references pointing to undefined-behaviourland.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: As you suggested, `std::reserve` avoids that, but good catch. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<buttonState>> buttonStates;` would also solve that, and don't fix an limit..